# jQuery: how can I hide/show a small column specific button on table column hover?

Tags: jquery, hover, show-hide

I need to hide/show (actually `slideDown/slideUp`) an 'add to cart' button underneath each table column.

My markup is a pretty basic table and the buttons positioning isn't causing any trouble either but what I cannot figure out is how to attach an event handler to the 'hover' event of a table **column** that will show the button inside that column then when hovering a different column, hide the currently showing and reveal the next one currently being hovered.

I've created a jsFiddle with a complete setup hopefully illustrating this issue properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/jannis/naz22/

I would appreciate it if you could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this I would suggest using floating, width-defined divs. The way you're doing it now it's unnecessarily complicated to isolate hovering over a "column". If they were divs you could simply say `$("div.column").hover(..)` to get the effect you're going for.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="features">
         <ul>
             <li>Webmail</li>
             ...
         </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
         <ul>
             <li><img src="" /></li>
             ...
             <li class="addit"><a href="#">Add It</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
         <ul>
             <li><img src="" /></li>
             ...
             <li class="addit"><a href="#">Add It</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
         <ul>
             <li><img src="" /></li>
             ...
             <li class="addit"><a href="#">Add It</a></li>
          </ul>
          ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Then some simple CSS

```
.product .addit { display:none; }
.product:hover .addit { display:block; }
```

or

```
.product:hover .addit { background: blue; }
```

or jQuery

```
$(".product").hover(
    function() { $(this).find(".addit").slideDown(); }, 
    function() { $(this).find(".addit").slideUp(); }
);
```

Comment: you could probably achieve this much more easily with divs

Comment: also, it might not be a good idea from a usability perspective to hide the ADD TO CART button entirely. If they never moused-over any product they might think you CAN'T add to cart!

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i was contemplating using floated div's with a nested `ul` instead of a table but semantically it's a data table so shouldn't it be in a `table` element?

Comment: Also: Good call about the usability aspect. Will have to revise this I think.

Comment: It could be a `table` but everything you'll try to do will be more complex as far as jQuery. r0m4n's answer will work but you can achieve the same thing with far less code with floating divs. Rather than slideUp/Down the "Add To Cart" element why not highlight it (background-color, opacity, etc) on hover of the div? You could do this all with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use divs, try this js instead:

```
var table = $('table.comparison'),

addBtns = table.find('.add-buttons a'); // the <a> is the button to be shown/hidden

table.data('col',''); // attribute to keep track of currently hovered column
var compare = "x";

$('td').hover(function() {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    var idx2 = "col-"+ idx;

    table.data('col', idx ); // set data-col to current column 

    if($(this).attr("class")!= compare){
       $('.add-buttons').find('a').slideUp('fast');  
       $('.add-buttons').find('.col-'+idx+' a').slideDown('fast');  
       compare = idx2;
    }  
});
$('table').hover(function() {},function(){
   $('.add-buttons').find('a').slideUp('fast');   
});
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your code. I tried it out and while it works better than what I had it has one major issue where when you do not leave the current column but move up and down from cell to cell the button `slideToggles` every time you hover a new cell…

Comment: hmmm... I couldn't replicate your issue but maybe a browser compatibility problem? what browser you test with?

Comment: This was in Firefox 3.6.11 on Mac, i can reproduce it by basically going into a column than not leaving the column but going up and down within the same column, every time i hover a new `td` it would fire the animation.